# Why can't I use import in ts file when executing with ts-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-cdk

I have a file in my src folder called foo.ts that looks like:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';

console.log('hello world');
const app = new cdk.App();
```

When I run `ts-node src/foo.ts` I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` If I remove the import console only it works... When I add `"type": "module",` to package.json I get `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts`

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
   // This is an alias to @tsconfig/node16: https://github.com/tsconfig/bases
   "extends": "ts-node/node16/tsconfig.json",
   // Most ts-node options can be specified here using their programmatic names.
   "ts-node": {
     // It is faster to skip typechecking.
     // Remove if you want ts-node to do typechecking.
     "transpileOnly": true,
     "files": true,
     "compilerOptions": {
       // compilerOptions specified here will override those declared below,
       // but *only* in ts-node.  Useful if you want ts-node and tsc to use
       // different options with a single tsconfig.json.
     }
   }, 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I noticed that ts-node complains about "Cannot use import statement outside a module" when there compiler options in tsconfig.json has `"module": "esnext"`, so I added `"module": "CommonJS"` in ts-node part to override it, and it worked. Apparently, if you use "CommonJS" compiler options, ts-node will transpile the imports into `require` etc., so it doesn't complain anymore. I haven't tested it for side effects, though.

Comment: Whenever I see `ts-node` I recomment trying `tsx` as it works better in random enviroments

Comment: Do you have an opinion about the compilation target, or are you just trying to get it to work as simply as possible?

Comment: @fedonev I would be open to a working solution that perhaps I could optimize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Remove the `"module": "esnext"` line.

NodeJS's recent support of [native ES Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) alongside the good-old CommonJS modules has introduced config confusion along with choice.  For the time being, as the Typescript [docs say](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module), *"you very likely want "CommonJS" for node projects"*.

How do you do this?  The nice people at [tsconfig/bases](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases) provide recommended `tsconfig` for various environments.  You are applying their [Node16 recommendations](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node16.json) with `extends`, which is great.  That is setting `"module": "commonjs"`, and setting other config that a Node16 environment needs.

But then your `compilerOptions` settings spoil the party by overriding the `extends` settings with `"module": "esnext"`, which is where the problems come in.  Remove that line and the others that conflict with the `tsconfig/bases` recommendations.

Tip:  I find it more transparent to copy-paste the recommended settings into the `compilerOptions` instead of indirectly referencing them with `extends`, commenting where the recommendations begin and end.  This way I am less likely to overwrite their good work.

Comment: You are a champion.